# Why does (almost) every answer in this question have a banner?

Tags: support

I admit I'm not overly familiar with how these banners work, but I was reading "[What is the word that is used to describe the oversimplification or non-academic discussion of a complex issue?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521738/what-is-the-word-that-is-used-to-describe-the-oversimplification-or-non-academic)" and noticed that the question and many of the answers have a banner stating:

> **Want to improve this post?** Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.

The question looks fine to me. The top answer, which also has a banner, looks great: it suggests a word, provides a definition sourced from a legitimate dictionary, and includes a link to a source.

I'm also quite confused about what the banner is even trying to say. The bolded part seems to be implying that the banner is specifically about editing an existing question or answer. The rest of it, which I would expect to be supporting information, seems to be completely unrelated, and reminds me of the guidance that used to be posted on top of high traffic questions that were attracting low quality answers. That aside, the unbolded text seems to be providing guidance for new *answers*. Put together, bolded 'heading' and unbolded support, they make no sense.

What is this banner trying to say, and was it *really* necessary it include it six times on the page? It's highly distracting. (And oddly enough, the much lower quality answers ranked lower don't have it.)

Comment: The main problem with the question (which then carries forward into a problem with the answers) is that a sample sentence was not supplied in a question seeking a single word answer. Without a sample sentence it is not clear what part of speech is sought and what context is envisaged. This is clearly requested in the Tour guide and Help section. And the first comment specifically draws attention to the requirement. The other problem is that _pedantic_, an example given, does not mean what the question is asking for.

Comment: If you look at the first version of those marked questions (the ones first submitted by their authors not the latest edited versions you see), they tend to be very short answers which are likely to be marked as 'low quality' (or attract a high rep user (having some mod powers) to mark it as such). -Why- there are so many on this one question... I think @NigelJ explained many reasons (which are common for SWRs).

Answer (score -1):

I very much dislike that type of banner and and its location. I find it confusing, if not actually contrary to the message it's trying to convey. The problem is that its interpretation is subjective in many cases.

I *personally* feel it should be given only a single time, and it should be at the bottom of the question, not at the top. (And, perhaps, it should be reworded a bit.)

I've argued (unsuccessfully) with a moderator about its use in the past. But, unfortunately, I can't recall the meta topic where it came up, so I can't link to it here.

However, the gist is it's meant to be an instruction to anybody answering the question to provide a long (or at least complete) answer. It's not meant as an admonition of the *question*—or even necessarily of any individual answer.

Another problem is that it's applied on a per-case basis by a moderator. The choice of applying it or not is also subjective.

Comment: No, that post notice is meant as an admonition of specific answers, which is why it has been applied to so many. If you think it should be applied to more answers, please do write a custom flag requesting it. I've done so several times before (though I'm not sure if at ELU).